# Display label outside of input in Angular Material

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

Is there any way in Angular Material to display the mat-label in the left outside of the mat-input ?
So far, I can't find anything in the Angular Material documentation that allows me to do this.

Greetings,

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way:

Please apply your own style:

```
<form style="display: flex">
    <label>Favorite food</label>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi" />
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

label css:

```
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```